# How to comment properly on stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

This may sound irrelevant but it bothers me. How can I comment on a question without making it an answer just as the mistake I did here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480222/when-did-windows-last-resume-from-standby-or-hibernate/12480586#12480586) and I would not mind if that can be edited for me appropriately.

Comment: you should really delete your 'comment as answer' post.  Chances are it will be deleted by someone else eventually; you should save them the time/effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start leaving comments at 50 reputation. An option will show up below the "share edit flag" options.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation